# onTouch events not working properly

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to extend a relative layout, and add a simple method to set an onTouchListener.

The problem is that after I set the listener, the only event that is being called is `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`

Other events are not being called.

Here is my code of the custom relative layout:

```
public class MyRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    public MyRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void setOnTouchEvent() {
        this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.d("myTextView", "onTouch event called");
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //only this event is being called
                    return false;
                default:
                    //other events are not being called
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Here is the xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.example.ontouchtest.MyRelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    MyRelativeLayout test;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        test = (MyRelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.test);
        test.setOnTouchEvent();
    }

}
```

From the logcat when printing the `MotionEvent` action I get 0:

`onTouch event called 0`

Comment: Instead Log.d("myTextView", "onTouch event called"); print the action, and attach it.

Comment: @Daniel It prints `0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that after action down you return `false`. turn it to `true` and then it will pass the other events too.

Comment: Yea iv seen the example from http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html

thanks.