# Android: setting colors for relativelayout inside onTouchListener

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, ontouchlistener

I am having some relativeLayout, inside which there are multiple textview and imagebuttons, so in order not to making `onTouchListener` one by one, I have implemented the below code:

```
    relative1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) 
        {
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN )
            {
                relative1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tran_black));
            }

            if((event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL))
            {
                relative1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
            }
            return false;
        }           
    });
```

### Question:

The `relative1` `RelativeLayout` has turned to `tran_black` color when pressed, but it fails to turn back to transparent upon `Action_up`.

How could that be ameneded? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return `true` instead of `false`.

According to [onTouch method doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch%28android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent%29), the return value is `True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.`
This means that when you return false, successive events will not be passed to your listener.

You can also refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291027/ontouch-events-not-working-properly/17291426#17291426) which has example in comments.

Answer (score 0):

1st clear previous color first then apply new color and also return true not the false,if you return false then it will listen touch only single time,not multiple times:

```
 relative1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) 
        {
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN )
            {
                relative1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tran_black));
            }

            if((event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL))
            {   //first clear previous color
                relative1.setBackgroundColor(0);
                //now set new color
                relative1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
            }
            return true;
        }           
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

just return true for onAction down,up and cancel else return `super.setOnTouchListener()` it will work..because it may  effect the  other listener for that relative layout