# android: onClickListener for relativelayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, onclicklistener

I have a relativelayout and have coded the `onTouchListener` to highlight background as follows:

```
    relative3.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) 
        {
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN )
            {
                relative3.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tran_grey));
            }

            if((event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL))
            {
                relative3.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
            }
            return true;
        }           
    });
```

and to perform an action upon `onClick`

```
    relative3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            custom_toast("Redirecting...");
        }
    });
```

### Question:

The relativelayout could show highlight upon `ACTION_DOWN` and turn back to transparent upon `ACTION_UP`. Yet it is clicked, the toast simply does not appear as coded.

How could that be modified? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the layout has the property `android:clickable="true"`

The proper way to do the color change is to use a background drawable xml with a pressed and normal state. If you do this in code, use getActionMasked() instead of getAction()

Comment: yes i have tried using the xml for the background of the relativelayout. Inside the relativelayout there are imagebutton and a some textviews. Pressing areas other than the imagebutton will trigger changing bgd color sucessfully, yet I dont understand why pressing ON the imagebutton, the bgd color will not change...therefore I tried to perform in the above way...

Comment: i have done so using xml for background at last. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Return false so so that your OnTouchListener doesn't consumed the event, so the clicklistener will work..

```
relative3.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN )
        {
            relative3.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tran_grey));
        }

        if((event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL))
        {
            relative3.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        }
        // change to false.
        return false;
    }           
});
```

More info : [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch(android.view.View, android.view.MotionEvent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch%28android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent%29)

Comment: if then the problem is that the RelativeLayout has turned to tran_black color when pressed, but it fails to turn back to transparent upon Action_up, which is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20787733/android-setting-colors-for-relativelayout-inside-ontouchlistener

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return false` in the `onTouch` method which tells the **OnTouchListener** that the click has not been consumed. Afterwards, it forwards the click event to `onClick` method of **OnClickListener**.